# What does \def\foo#{...} mean?

Tags: macros

I came across this idiom recently:

```
\def\foo#{...}
```

That is, a hash but no parameter number. What might be the purpose of this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It grabs the content until the next brace (or group). For example:

```
\def\foo#1#{«#1»}

\starttext
\foo random content {until braces}
\stoptext
```

gives

[image]