# Why does \tag require braces while \frac doesn't?

Tags: fractions, braces, tags

I'm used to using `\tag` without braces like `\tag3` instead of `\tag{3}` in Markdown+MathJax, where it works as fine as does `\frac12` in normal LaTeX. But when I tried to do this in a real `.tex` source processed with `pdflatex`, I got some errors.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[f(x)=\frac32\tag1\]

\end{document}
```

And this is what `pdflatex` says

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
>  restricted \write18 enabled.
> entering extended mode
> (./test.tex
> LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
> Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
> Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
> For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
> No file test.aux.
> Runaway argument?
> 1\] 
> ! Paragraph ended before \tag was complete.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \par 
> l.6
> ```

When I surround the `1` with braces, it compiles fine, and I get the expected PDF output.
So I wonder, why does `\tag` require braces while `\frac` doesn't? Is there some difference in "type" of the object, like e.g. `\tag` being a package-supplied facility while `\frac` is from the language core (doesn't need `\usepackage` at least) or something like that?

Comment: yes they are differently defined. Better don't be lazy and avoid argument braces -- as you can see it can break.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The macro `\frac` is defined (robustly) as

```
\frac#1#2 -> \begingroup #1 \endgroup \@@over #2
```

where `\@@over` is (a copy of) the TeX primitive. So in this case you can indeed write `\frac12` and it will be the same as `\frac{1}{2}`. A lot of people, included myself, will tell you not to do this. (Although for such short fractions I don't always follow my own advice...)

On the other hand, at the beginning of displaymath `\tag` is `\let` to `\tag@in@display`, whose definition reads

```
\def\tag@in@display#1#{\relax\tag@in@display@a{#1}}
```

The tricky bit is the `#` before the opening brace of the replacement text. TeX looks for the first argument up to an opening brace (later it will check if this first argument is a star `*`). For details on how this mechanism works I refer to the questions [Grab to #{ macro arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39525/82917) (in particular [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39526/82917)) and [Macros with # as the last parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13333/82917). But the short answer is: TeX is scanning for an opening brace to collect the argument `#1` and at some point finds the empty line (which is converted to a new paragraph), which isn't allowed, and hence the `Paragraph ended` error.

Comment: I think the last sentence is not correct. TeX finds `\par` (namely the empty line after `\]`) _before_ expanding `\tag`, while it is scanning for its argument. It isn't looking for a closing brace but scanning for the opening brace delimiting that argument.

Comment: @schtandard Yeah, that's absolutely true. I've edited.